# Pyspark SQL job slowed down by reading fixed width instead of parquet

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I have a script that consists of several joins and a few other basic operations.  When I was reading parquet format data the script would run and write the new parquet data quickly. I recently updated the script to accept fixed width data and determine the columns based on given specifications.

This has slowed down the script by a factor of 10.

I have tried playing with the spark configs and different partitions of the data but the runtime is still abysmal.

Comment: You need to provide some code and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Parquet and ORC are optimized formats for columnar reading/writing, therefore work well in SparkSQL dataframes.

Plaintext CSV/TSV are much slower, by design, as entire rows of data need parsed and extracted again and again during processing.

There's likely nothing you're doing wrong here. If you need fast processing speeds overall, then you'll need a proper database that can optimize your queries, and not be processing raw files